# need php api help

Tags: php, web-services, api

hi friends i am trying to solve how i can access the halo reach api for get states bungie has released a api for this here is the link http://www.bungie.net/fanclub/statsapi/Group/Resources/Article.aspx?cid=545064

how can i access this service via php and display some stats need help thanks

i am trying like this

```
 <?php
 require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
 $wsdl  = "http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/ReachApiJson.svc?wsdl";
 $client = new soapclient($wsdl, 'wsdl');
 $parameters['parameters']['apikey'] =   "xxx";
 $result = $client->call("GetGameMetadata", $parameters);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consuming JSON in PHP is pretty simple.

```
<?PHP
$uri = 'http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/game/metadata/xxx';
if (! $json = file_get_contents($uri)){ //cURL can be faster and more flexible, but this ought to work
    trigger_error('API call failed!');
}
if (! $result = json_decode($json)){
    trigger_error('API returned bad data?');
    //maybe log some stuff here, so you can debug.
}
print_r($result); //see what you got.
```

Comment: can you please tell me how i can do this with curl

Comment: i try this code and i try many times with diffrent ways nothing works for me thanks for your help